# How to integrate a probability density function with coefficient?

Tags: calculus

I want to ask how we can integrate the following function, $f(T)$, which is near Gaussian.

$$ \large \intop_{-k}^k \frac{2a}{x^{2}} \cdot {e^ {-(\frac{a}{x}-u)^{2}/b^2}} dx$$

Thanks,

Comment: Let $w=\frac{a}{x}-u$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let  $v=\frac{a}{x}-u$, then $dv=\frac{-a}{x^2}$: $$\large \intop_{\frac{a}{-k}-u}^{\frac{a}{k}-u} -{}  2{e^ {-(v)^{2}/b^2}} dv$$

Comment: Thanks man, that was helpful. I worked it out to the definite integral and use the error function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $w=\dfrac{a}{x}-u$.  Then $dw=-\dfrac{a}{x^2}\,dx$. That will bring you to familiar territory.

Or else you can make a  trickier substitution and reduce to the standard normal in one step.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just clarify the function again. do u think the integration by parts will work with your hint?

Comment: @user61108:  The hint reduces the problem to the integral of a constant times $e^{-w^2/b^2}$. This does not have an elementary antiderivative. With the right substitution, you can reduce it to a definite integral of $e^{-t^2/2}$, in other words of the standard normal density function. One cannot get a formula for the indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I tried to substitute t=2w/b to get e^-t^2/2 but get w^2 now in the integral. any advice?

Comment: Yes, $t=\sqrt{2}w/b$, or equivalently $w=tb/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: thank you again. now i got dt and reduce to the definite integral. Now i can use erf with the updated limits. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Careful, there are lots of messy constants. By the way, I felt guilty about the magic substitution without explanation. It really is quite simple. Let's do it in **one** step. We want $(\frac{x}{a}-u)^2/b^2$ to be $t^2/2$. That certainly will happen if $(\frac{a}{x}-b)=t/\sqrt{2}$. This is a "good" substitution because the derivative of $\frac{a}{x}-u$ is basically sitting in front of our integrand. By the way, don't forget about the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ stuff.

Comment: Thanks again. It works perfectly now